# How to solve 'java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error' while using okhttp to post a big data

Tags: java

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.When I use `okhttp` or `httpclient` to post a big data, a java.net.SocketException is throwed.The big data is a big string which is is encoded as base64 from a 52M size file.I conducted capture with `wireshark`, but nothing.However when I used `postman` to do this, it worked.

I increased the `max-http-post-size` and the connectTimeout, soTimeout, but it was useless.

The server is only a simple post restful interface which built by spring boot.

The client code is:

```java
String text = ConvertUtil.convertTimeBetaTo2017(video.toJSONString());

      final DigestAuthenticator authenticator = new DigestAuthenticator(
          new Credentials(this.serverInfo.getUsername(), this.serverInfo.getPassword())
        );

        final Map<String, CachingAuthenticator> authCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
          .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
          .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
          .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
          .authenticator(new CachingAuthenticatorDecorator(authenticator, authCache))
          .addInterceptor(new AuthenticationCacheInterceptor(authCache))
          .build();

        String url = this.serverInfo.getServer() + VbankRestfulUri.VideoSlices.getValue();
        final MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url(url)
          .addHeader("client-info", this.serverInfo.getClientInfo())
          .addHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
          .addHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked")
          .addHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
          .addHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block")
          .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate")
          .addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
          .addHeader("Expires", "0")
          .post(RequestBody.create(text, mediaType))
          .build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                return new Result(true, "操作成功");
            }
            else {
                return new Result(false, "操作失败");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new Result(false, e.getMessage());
        }
```

The exception is :

```java
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at okio.OutputStreamSink.write(Okio.kt:65)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$sink$1.write(AsyncTimeout.kt:106)
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.kt:181)
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.kt:39)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$KnownLengthSink.write(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:292)
    at okio.ForwardingSink.write(ForwardingSink.kt:29)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange$RequestBodySink.write(Exchange.kt:222)
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.kt:181)
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.kt:92)
    at okhttp3.RequestBody$Companion$toRequestBody$2.writeTo(RequestBody.kt:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:59)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:37)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:82)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:84)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:71)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at com.burgstaller.okhttp.AuthenticationCacheInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationCacheInterceptor.java:49)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:184)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:66)
```